# Statically compile SQLite into a VB.Net application?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

System.Data.SQLite (SDS) is apparently the most popular way to use SQLite from a .Net application.

I was wondering if

- SDS requires shipping the SQLite DLL in addition, or if SDS includes
  the SQLite source code, and
- SDS can be statically compiled into a
  VB.Net application of it can only be shipped as a DLL?

Thank you.

Comment: its a net wrapper for unmanaged code. You need to ship the dll, and ensure visual c++ runtime is installed on target mechines

Comment: And don't forget the 64/32 bit checks. (Different DLL versions)

Answer (score 0):

To expand on my comment, SDS is a .net wrapper for unmanaged code, so you will need to ship your release code with a copy of the DLL.

As Steve mentions, there are 32 and 64bit versions of the DLL, and as i discovered after much frustration, you must have the corresponding visual c++ runtime installed on the target machine, so if you deploy the 32bit version onto a 64bit machine, it will need the 32bit c++ runtime environment installed.

An alternative that i am currently looking into but havent had time to test is csharpe-sqlite, a pure .net implementation:

http://code.google.com/p/csharp-sqlite/

Coded in c# as the name suggests, but of course usable in any .net language including vb.net

Comment: Thanks much for the info about having to match the DLL + C++ runtime. C#SQLite seems deadware, as its last update was in Aug 2011.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it's quite easy to compile System.Data.SQLite.dll to the does not require C++ runtime. For example if you [download](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki) source code and follow the [build procedures](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/build.wiki) you'll find statically linked (no C/C++ runtime required) copy of System.Data.SQLite.dll in the following path:

```
<your-src-root>\bin\<2008 or 2010>\<Win32 or x64>\ReleaseStatic
```

For example if your source is in `C:\Work\sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.80.0` then statically linked binary for Win32 and .NET 3.5 (VS 2008) will be located in:

```
C:\Work\sqlite-netFx-source-1.0.80.0\bin\2008\Win32\ReleaseStatic
```

Furthermore since System.Data.SQLite.dll is a [mixed-mode assembly](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0w2664k.aspx) consisting of a managed .netmodule and native .obj file linked together using [link.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0zzbyt4.aspx), it is possible to build your app as a .netmodule as well and link it together with SQLite into a single mixed mode assembly.

The resulting assembly will still be either Win32 or x64, however since almost all x64 machines will have no problem running Win32 code you can just settle on Win32 as long as:

- Your app is an .exe or a .dll the is always loaded into a Win32 process, and
- You don't use any of x64 specific advantages such as larger address space or using unmanaged code available only in x64